# Calcular el porcentaje de valores comunes entre una columna y una lista, en base a las categorías de otra columna

Tags: r, lista, dataframe

Estoy bastante atascado con este ejercicio por lo que agradecería que alguien me pudiera echar una mano. Tengo un **dataframe** con dos columnas, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| 100100 | rs-1 |
| 100100 | rs1597782599 |
| 100100 | rs1603359091 |
| 100100 | rs1603359205 |
| 100300 | rs372751467 |
| 100300 | rs3732413 |
| 100300 | rs387907031 |
| 100300 | rs9852894 |
| 100800 | rs-1 |
| 100800 | rs121913114 |
| 100800 | rs144995231 |
| 100800 | rs17883400 |
| 100800 | rs761325047 |
| 101000 | rs1060503667 |
| 101000 | rs1060503668 |
| 101000 | rs1060503669 |
| 101000 | rs1060503670 |
| 101000 | rs1060503671 |

Y una **lista de códigos rs** como en el dataset$V2.

Lo que intento obtener es el porcentaje de códigos rs comunes entre la columna 2 y la lista, pero agrupando por los códigos del dataset$V1. Por ejemplo:

| V1 | Common % |
| --- | --- |
| 100100 | 25% |
| 100300 | 40% |
| 100800 | 50% |
| 101000 | 100% |

He probado varias opciones, pero sin éxito. Por ejemplo, estoy probando con la opción tidyverse group_by(dataframe$V1), pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo concatenar el cálculo del porcentaje común.

Muchísimas gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola. Siento que no se entienda correctamente. Lo que quiero saber es de un vector de códigos rs (por ejemplo: rs-1, rs3009, rs45678, rs 900100), qué porcentaje cubre los rs en la segunda columna que hay asociados a cada código de la primera columna. Por ejemplo, para el código 100100 de la primera columna, el porcentaje de los códigos rs-1, rs1597782599, rs1603359091 y rs1603359205 que están incluidos en la lista. En este ejemplo solo estaría incluido rs-1, por lo tanto el porcentaje de cobertura sería del 25%.

Comment: Entiendo que para el grupo 100100 hay solo 1 elemento en comun, por lo que corresponde al 25%, pero en el grupo 2 100300, existen 0 elementos en comun con toda la lista, por lo que el porcentaje seria 0, para el grupo 100800 el porcentaje seria 0.2? ya que tambien tiene solo 1 elemento en comun con toda la lista

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a guiar por lo que has explicado más que por el ejemplo. Entiendo que lo que buscas es por cada grupo de `V1` saber que porcentaje de todos los `V2` coinciden con un vector de casos que indicarías antes.

Si es esto, podrías hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

casos <- c('rs-1', 'rs372751467', 'rs9852894','rs1060503668')

df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(porc = sum(V2 %in% casos) / n())

      V1  porc
   <int> <dbl>
1 100100  0.25
2 100300  0.5 
3 100800  0.2 
4 101000  0.2
```

---